# Improving Blazor Server Startup

Tags: .net, performance, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am running a .NET 7 Blazor Server application on IIS. I am aware that Blazor startup is relatively slow. Are there any tips for improving the startup time? Maybe IIS settings or within the application itself?

Comment: Blazor server starts relatively fast. Do you have a concrete problem?

Comment: Hi @HH. My blazor server apps take about twice as long to load for the user compared to mvc/razor apps. Once loaded they are a breeze.

Comment: The landing page loads twice if you're pre-rendering, so have a lightweight landing page.  " twice as long".  250ms to 500ms or 1 minute to 2 minutes?